# Chrome OS USB/Bluetooth access

Tags: bluetooth, usb, google-chrome-os

Is it possible to develop an application that runs on Chrome OS which have access to USB / Bluetooth device?
I need to have read and write access - what is the optimal solution: chrome app / native client / something else?

Thanks,
Yaniv

Answer (score 0):

A Chrome App is probably your best bet:

[API list](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index)

Notice that Bluetooth and Bluetooth low energy are in there, as well as USB.

You can find [samples](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/samples) for these APIs on GitHub as well.